# How to stretch items of horiziontal ListVIew UWP XAML?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I can't seem to figure out how I can stretch the items of my horizontal listview.

I have a list of items, and each one of those items contain a list of other items. Which means I have a list nested in another list. Since I want to display the items of the nested list horizontally,  I have used StackPanel.

```
<ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListView.ItemsPanel>
```

However it seems like it is not possible to stretch and make all the rectangles have the same width, while filling out the page, with StackPanel. Even with setting the HorizontalContentAlignment and HorizontalAlignment of the ListView to "Stretch". Is there a way to solve this problem? It seems like I should use Grid somehow, but since the list length of the nested list varies, I'm not sure.

Below is how it looks like, I just want the width of the rectangle to stretch and have the same width, filling out the empty space. The width of the rectangles should adjust if you make the app width bigger or smaller.

[image: This is what I'm getting]

This is how I want it to look
[image: Want it to look like this]

Comment: With a stackpanel this is not possible. You may want to use the Windows Community Toolkit can use the UniformGrid panel instead of stackpanel, and set MaxRows to 1.

Comment: Thank you! Using UniformGrid panel instead of Stackpanel made it work as I wanted it to.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake, you comments looks solved the problem, could you mind converter it as answer for this problem.